# Происхождение слова товарищ

Tags: этимология

По Европе гуляет слово **комрад**,  происходящее от испанского **комарада** (звучит как **кому** **рады**) - сокамерник - солдат из одной камеры - казармы. Это слово переводится как **товарищ**. Наше **друг** так же из военной среды - **дружина**. А **товарищ** откуда? Там же вариться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Товарищ - от товар, исходное значение  - компаньон по торговле. В др.-рус. языке с 14 века.

Суффикс ИЩ, возможно, был другой  (например, isь или ysь), но потом изменился под влиянием слова "товарище" - стан, где производилась торговля (из словаря Черных).

Comment: Мне нравится ваш ответ, хотя и выглядит слово "товарище" так, словно речь об огромном товаре( чудище, детище), я слышал о "торжищах".

Comment: Само слово *товаръ* обозначало - стан. Товары и товарища - станы, обозы и тп.

Comment: Да, верно, стан назывался и товаром тоже. А суффикс ИЩ здесь обозначает не оценку, а используется для образования существительного (сравнить: зимовище, убежище, сборище, также торг - торжище).

Comment: Здесь ср. подробно рассматривается тюркский след и приводится слов. статья из Фасмера с версиями, что "ищ" - не славянский суффикс, а второй корень составного слова, означающий "спутник" (в общем вьючном караване).
http://korneslov.ru/publ/22-1-0-177

Comment: Поучительная статья.

Comment: Если бы ИЩ был суффиксом (был ли он isь или ysь), в русском языке остались бы и другие слова с этим суффиксом. Но их нет. Вообще нет. ЫШ - есть (малыш, крепыш, плохиш...). ИЩЕ - вполне нормально. Но совершенно невероятен переход "товарище" (торжище) > "товарищ" (человек).

__Рясянен__ (по ссылке @Alex_ander) выглядит более убедительно со вторым корнем "спутник".

Comment: @stopkran, как же их нет? А ристалИЩе, убежИЩе, топорИЩе, человечИЩе? Вот суффикса ИЩЕ в русском языке действительно нет.